# Como atualizar uma div especifica na página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu gostaria que depois que o `$ajax` terminasse, atualizasse a tag `div` que tem como id `#coments`, pois nessa `div` carrega os dados do banco de dados.

`HTML`

```
<div id="coments">
    <!-- // Query dos comentários PAI -->
    <div class="you-coment-post">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="logo-face.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="box-you-write-post-coment">
            <span class="title-you-post-coment">Ramon</span>
            <p class="you-text-post-coment">
                E aeeee             </p>
        </div>
    </div>         
    <!-- // Fim do Bloco -->
</div>
```

`AJAX`

```
function checkKeyPai() {
    var tamanho = $("#comentario-pai").val().length;
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
        var textareaPai = $('#comentario-pai').val();
        var posicao = $('#comentario-pai').attr("data-posicao");
        var idUser = $('#comentario-pai').attr("data-idUser");
        var idPost = $('#comentario-pai').attr("data-idPost");
        if (tamanho < 10) {
            alert("Você precisa digitar pelo menos 10 caracteres");
        } else {
            if (idUser == "") {
                alert("Você precisa está logado!");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                url: "/addComentario.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "textareaPai=" + textareaPai + "&idUser=" + idUser + "&idPost=" + idPost + "&posicao=" + posicao + "",
                dataType: "html"

                }).done(function(resposta) {
                        alert(resposta);

                }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);

                }).always(function() {      
                    console.log("completou");
                });

            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Você sabe o que representam os métodos `done`, `fail` e `always` que você utilizou?

Comment: O .done sempre é executado, enquanto que .success só é chamado caso ocorra sucesso.

Comment: E também que os métodos done e fail estão relacionados ao retorno da função $.ajax. Apenas o always que não compreendi muito ainda.

Comment: O método `done` só executado se a requisição foi bem sucedida e é nele que você deverá fazer a atualização da `div`.

Comment: Mas ae que ta minha dúvida como faço essa atualização, e que sou bem iniciante ainda.

Comment: Aí vai depender do que seria essa "atualização". Edite a pergunta e adicione mais detalhes sobre isso, explicando qual é a `div` e qual será o novo conteúdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O retorno do ajax já é o html pronto para inserir dentro da div? Se sim basta tu fazer um  `$('#coments').html(resposta) no .done`

O método .html substitui todo o conteúdo html do selector que você informar, neste caso, uma div.

Comment: Com isso já da para me ajudar obrigado!